# How to reboot a virtual machine using Softlayer Python API

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I cannot find where using `SoftLayer Python API VSManager` to reboot or `power-off/on` a virtual machine instance.

The operations are described in the `XMLRPC API` at:

http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

but I can't find equivalent at:

http://softlayer-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/managers/vs.html

Answer (score 4):

Indeed the manager does not have that implementation you have to make api calls for that here some examples:

```
"""
Power off Guest

The scripts will look for a VSI which has an specific
hostname and the it powers off the VSI by making a single call
to the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::powerOff method.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Acount/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Acount/getVirtualGuests
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setTags

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

"""
# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
#
# Generate an API key at the SoftLayer Customer Portal:
# https://manage.softlayer.com/Administrative/apiKeychain
"""
username = 'set me'
key = 'set me'

# The name of the machine you wish to power off
virtualGuestName = 'rctest'

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=username, api_key=key)


try:
    # Getting all virtual guest that the account has:
    virtualGuests = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getVirtualGuests()
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """
    print("Unable to retrieve hardware. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))

# Looking for the virtual guest
virtualGuestId = ''
for virtualGuest in virtualGuests:
    if virtualGuest['hostname'] == virtualGuestName:
        virtualGuestId = virtualGuest['id']

try:
    # Power off the virtual guest
    virtualMachines = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].powerOff(id=virtualGuestId)
    print ("powered off")
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """
    print("Unable to power off the virtual guest"
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

--

```
"""
Reboot Virtual Guest.
It reboots a SoftLayer Virtual Guest


Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/rebootDefault

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# From pprint import pprint as pp
# For nice debug output
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# If you don't know your server id you can call getVirtualGuests() in the
# SoftLayer_Account API service to get a list of Virtual Guests
serverId = 10403817

# Create a connection to API service.
client = SoftLayer.Client(
        username=API_USERNAME,
        api_key=API_KEY
)

# Reboot the Virtual Guest
try:

    result = client['Virtual_Guest'].rebootDefault(id=serverId)
    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to reboot the server faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

`slcli vs power_off` and `slcli vs power_on` should do the trick. [Working with Virtual Servers](http://softlayer-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli/vs.html)

Maybe this helps, too. [Source of the reboot functionality from the cli](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/bbaf562fb76536c5cc652e356729723f38f48b66/SoftLayer/CLI/hardware/power.py#L35)